# VBA array functions: push, pop, shift, unshift

Tags: array, vba, excel, vectors, winapi

I want to write my snake game procedurally, using as much windows call as I can so as to practice. Looking into GetAsyncKeyState to capture keyboard inputs and play sound functions. Also making a sweet user interface. Fun!

Also shout to bytecomb for providing example as to how to traverse the array structure, used his code function to find ptr to element in array!!

https://github.com/Evanml2030/Excel-ArrayFunctions

**API CALLS**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function VarPtrArray Lib "VBE7" Alias "VarPtr" _
        (ByRef Var() As Any) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemoryI Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
        (ByVal dst As LongPtr, ByVal src As LongPtr, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemoryII Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
        (ByRef dst As SAFEARRAY, ByVal src As LongPtr, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal vKey As Long) As Boolean
```

**DATA STRUCTS**

```
Private Type SAFEARRAY_BOUND
    cElements    As Long
    lLbound      As Long
End Type

Private Type SAFEARRAY
    cDims        As Integer
    fFeatures    As Integer
    cbElements   As Long
    cLocks       As Long
    pvData       As LongPtr
    rgsabound(0) As SAFEARRAY_BOUND
End Type

Public Type TestStruct
    Column       As Long
    Row          As Long
End Type

Private Const TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH = 8
```

**FUNCTIONS**

```
Public Function ArrayPush(ByRef ArrayOriginal() As TestStruct, ByRef ElementToAdd As TestStruct) As TestStruct()
Dim NewLength      As Long
Dim CopiedBytes    As Long
Dim NewBytes       As Long

    NewLength = UBound(ArrayOriginal) + 1
    ReDim ArrayPush(NewLength)

    CopiedBytes = NewLength * TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH
    NewBytes = TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH

    CopyMemoryI ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayPush, 0, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayOriginal, 0, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), CopiedBytes
    CopyMemoryI ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayPush, NewLength, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), VarPtr(ElementToAdd), NewBytes
End Function

Public Function ArrayPop(ByRef ArrayOriginal() As TestStruct) As TestStruct()
Dim NewLength      As Long
Dim CopiedBytes    As Long

    NewLength = UBound(ArrayOriginal) - 1
    ReDim ArrayPop(NewLength)

    CopiedBytes = UBound(ArrayOriginal) * TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH

    CopyMemoryI ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayPop, 0, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayOriginal(), 0, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), CopiedBytes
End Function

Public Function ArrayShift(ByRef ArrayOriginal() As TestStruct, ByRef ElementToAdd As TestStruct) As TestStruct()
Dim NewLength      As Long
Dim CopiedBytes    As Long
Dim NewBytes       As Long

    NewLength = UBound(ArrayOriginal) + 1
    ReDim ArrayShift(NewLength)

    CopiedBytes = NewLength * TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH
    NewBytes = TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH

    CopyMemoryI ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayShift, 1, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayOriginal, 0, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), CopiedBytes
    CopyMemoryI ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayShift, 0, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), VarPtr(ElementToAdd), NewBytes
End Function

Public Function ArrayUnshift(ByRef ArrayOriginal() As TestStruct) As TestStruct()
Dim NewLength      As Long
Dim CopiedBytes    As Long

    NewLength = UBound(ArrayOriginal) - 1
    ReDim ArrayUnshift(NewLength)

    CopiedBytes = UBound(ArrayOriginal) * TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH

    CopyMemoryI ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayUnshift, 0, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), ArrayElementGetPointer(ArrayOriginal, 1, TESTSTRUCT_BYTELENGTH), CopiedBytes
End Function

Public Function ArrayElementGetPointer(ByRef Arr() As TestStruct, ByVal ElementIndex As Long, ByVal ElementByteLength As Long) As LongPtr
Dim ptrToArrayVar  As LongPtr
Dim ptrToSafeArray As LongPtr
Dim ptrToArrayData As LongPtr
Dim ptrCursor      As LongPtr
Dim uSAFEARRAY     As SAFEARRAY

    ptrToArrayVar = VarPtrArray(Arr)
    CopyMemoryI VarPtr(ptrToSafeArray), ptrToArrayVar, 8
    CopyMemoryII uSAFEARRAY, ptrToSafeArray, LenB(uSAFEARRAY)
    ptrToArrayData = uSAFEARRAY.pvData
    ptrCursor = ptrToArrayData + (ElementIndex * ElementByteLength)
    ArrayElementGetPointer = ptrCursor
End Function
```

Comment: Quick thing, I've got to ask why you use `Debug.Print` rather than `Debug.Assert` for your tests, the latter will actually let you know when something has gone wrong -  rather than relying on your eyes to tell you. Or indeed switch to [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/UnitTesting) for some proper *unit tests*

Comment: had never seen .assert used, will explore. thanks. i have rubber duck but have barely gotten the indentation features working, will look into the unit testing. just time!!

Comment: by got working i mean understand how to use!